# Accessing and controlling services on Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, android-service

I would like to create an android app/service that will control Android services, in particular the [Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). This is different from the [playing a audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) file, in my case the user has already launched the Media Player with their own song/playlist and wish to send skip/stop/... commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AOSP Media Player has no public documented and supported API. Moreover, the app you think of as the "Media Player" does not exist on all devices.